# Open a document located in oneDrive/sharepoint directly in Desktop Word using ms-word protocol

Tags: sharepoint, ms-word, microsoft-graph-api, office365, onedrive

I want to open an existing file in oneDrive/sharepoint from our application directly in Desktop word.
I used ms-word protocol (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/office-uri-schemes),
but it doesn't open the word directly, it shows a dialog (attached image) first. What I want to achieve is to implement "Open Word" functionality directly, I don't want to see any dialog.
The protocol looks like this: 'ms-word:ofe|u|'+ wordfile_url

[image]

Comment: This is not a programming question and, as such, is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Questions on general usage of Microsoft Word should be asked on an appropriate end-user forum or oneDrive/sharepoint forum.

Comment: The above is a default behavior and it will throw the message (not error) if you want to open it with the desktop installed app(word).